# Why System.Security.Cryptography SHA256 hash cannot be decrypted by online hash tool?

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography

I tried generating hash on this [website](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) and decrypt it on this [hash decryptor website](https://hashtoolkit.com/reverse-hash?hash=f0ab5ee19b9a50c0d2bdd253c8bbcb8bed835a0d3a503c7c6a412f04930dff56) and it can really decrypt but not the hash generated from System.Security.Cryptography. Why? Does it mean that Cryptography namespace uses different algorithm?

Code reference using .Net Core 2.2

```
    static byte[] calculateHash(string source)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding converter = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] sourceBytes = converter.GetBytes(source);

        HashAlgorithm hasher = SHA256.Create();
        byte[] hash = hasher.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);

        return hash;
    }

    static void showHash(string source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Has for {0} is:", source);
        byte[] hash = calculateHash(source);
        foreach(byte b in hash)
        {
            Console.Write("{0:X}",b);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. Be sure to have the `source` value **in the code in the question**.

Comment: Try Console.Write(“{0:X2}”), you’re losing the leading zero for any byte less than 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHA256 is a ***hashing*** function, not an encryption function. Since SHA256 is not an encryption function, it cannot be decrypted.

What you mean is probably reversing it. In that case, SHA256 cannot be reversed because it's a one-way function.

The site you reference is simply a database of known hash values and input strings. The obvious limitation of such a tool is that it cannot be used for hashes that haven't yet been added.

Comment: Thanks for noting **The site you reference is simply a database of known hash values and input strings.** So it means that the generated hash by Cryptography namespace is not know to the site?

Comment: @RonaldAbellano yes, the generated hash for your specific input string is not known. There are essentially an infinite number of possible input string and hash value combinations.